# custom header and footer in print screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am using the print function in javascript and in the print screen on top of the data it shows the url i.e. localhost and on the footer too I want to change the header and footer to something else a logo and some headings how can i do it i am printing a table and this is the code of the function using to print

```
 document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function() {
    printElement(document.getElementById("myTable"));
}

function printElement(elem) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }

    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();
}
```

It would be great if any of you help me to modify the header and footer

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't have full control of the print page header/footer other than modifying the corresponding information (page title / URL). Though you can hide those lines in a lil bit hacky way: set print page margins to 0 and then compensate them with body margins or whatever. And you can try to add a custom header/footer with `position: fixed`. Which won't be working in every browser also. And so your CSS will be smth like:

```
@media print {
  @page { margin: 0mm; }

  body { margin: 20mm; }

  .print-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: -10mm;
  }
}
```